# Prevent HttpContext.Current.Session being reused on ipad/iphone

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a system which stores a variable of type `SessionService` (My class) on the `HttpContext.Current.Session`

I know there are issues with Chrome reusing the session across tabs and windows.

So I put code in to ask user to close all windows/tabs with the application if the `HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionService"]` is not null when the application gets to the Index of my Home Controller

This is to avoid issues with users who have access to different logins for the system

This works perfectly on PCs.  If I close all tabs then start a new tab, I am able to carry on as normal

However, on an IPAD or IPhone, this doesnt happen and the original session seems to hang around?

Has anyone have it's solution?
I think this must be related to the devices using cached pages. Am i right?

Comment: You should always keep in mind the tips at [think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). There are few reasons why an MVC application actually needs it. If the data you are trying to keep around is not sensitive, the most practical fix would be to load it into the view and then post it back for the next request to read it, which would always work regardless of how the browser decided to implement cookies (whether they are shared between tabs or not).

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the links, I need the information stored in my session service to be available throughout my entire application, which can have new tabs loaded, not really sure how to go about the post it back option,etc?